# Doesn't have a default value error ! Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have referred all the other questions asked and did what they have told. Still i cant get rid of default_value error. I have added multiple connections. So i have 3 databases : Users , companya , companyb.
Company-A and Company-B has same structure.
Stocks have tag_no as primary key and i have specified it in model too.
Inside Stock model I have created a constructor to dynamically switch models based on users company.
Even after all this i keep getting this error.
I tried changing strict to false inside **database.php** but.. all the entries are showing value 0. So I stopped trying that.

So what can i do to solve this. Please help!

Below is my schemas:

For Users:

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('company')->default('companya');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->string('password');                
                $table->string('user_type',50)->default('user');                
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

For company-A and company-B:

```
Schema::connection('companya')->create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string('tag_no')->index();
            $table->string('stock_type');          
            $table->timestamps();            
        });
```

Here is my Stock Model:

```
class Stock extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'tag_no';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [        
        'tag_no',
        'stock_type',             
    ];

    public function __construct() {
        if ( Auth::check() ) {
        $this->connection = Auth::user()->company;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){            
            if (Stock::where('tag_no','=',$request->input('tag_no'))->exists()) { 
                return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Tag number already used!');                
                }      

                    $stock = Stock::create([
                        'tag_no' => $request->input('tag_no'),
                        'stock_type' => $request->input('stock_type'),

                    ]);
                }         

                if($stock){                  
                    return redirect()->route('stocks.index', ['stocks'=> $stock->tag_no])
                    ->with('success' , 'Stock created successfully');

                }               

        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new Stock');        
    }
```

Comment: When do you get this error? And what entries show value `0`? Please show us the code you use for querying.

Comment: Please show us the full error message. And what do you want to insert into db?

Comment: its actually showing all the values.. in the Whoops page.

Comment: But it says tag_no has no default value

Comment: Should i try insert? instead of create

Comment: It is beacouse tour tag_no input is null and doesn't have any value. please make a dd() from $request->input('tag_no') and comment the result

Comment: I solved my issue.... just changed create to insert . Its working fine now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed create to insert and removed stocks parameter.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){            
            if (Stock::where('tag_no','=',$request->input('tag_no'))->exists()) { 
                return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Tag number already used!');                
                }      

                    $stock = Stock::insert([
                        'tag_no' => $request->input('tag_no'),
                        'stock_type' => $request->input('stock_type'),

                    ]);
                }         

                if($stock){                  
                    return redirect()->route('stocks.index')
                    ->with('success' , 'Stock created successfully');

                }               

        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new Stock');        
    }
```